# Selenium test case getting failed when node RDP is minimized

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid

I have Selenium grid Hub/Nodes configured in Virtual Machines (Windows Server) managed by Jenkins. I am accessing the node machines via RDP. The problem is when the test are started and if the Node machine RDP is open but with RDP window minimized, the tests are getting failed.

If the Node RDP is opened (I can see the browser actions) or if I disconnect the RDP session, the tests are working fine. The node has IE11 browser. Is this is how it works usually or am I missing some configuration.

Please provide your insights. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats seems strange, can you post the errors you are getting.

Comment: @PankajKatiyar, the test is fairly simple. It should click on the login link in the application home page and checks for the element. I am getting 'org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException'. It looks obvious that the click never happened.